# Calculating what a spinning wheel lands on

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

when I spin the wheel I am unable to output the correct number that I have landed on (I always seem to get it 1 or more off depending on what i set the spinSpeed variable to). I have watched a video on how to get what number the pointer is sitting on which I have implemented into my code(the array and the 3 souts). Any help would be appreciated.

[image: The wheel that spinns]

```java
public class RoulettePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    int x;
    int y;
    int rotationAngle = 0;
    Image image;
    double spinSpeed;
    double speedDeduction;
   // int[] Slices = {0,27,10,25,29,12,8,19,31,18,6,21,33,16,4,23,35,14,2,0,28,9,26,30,11,7,20,32,17,5,22,34,15,3,21,36,13,1};

    int[] Slices = {1,13,36,21,3,15,34,22,5,17,32,20,7,11,30,26,9,28,0,2,14,35,23,4,16,33,21,6,18,31,19,8,12,29,25,10,27,0};

    public RoulettePanel() {
        image = new ImageIcon("src/images/rouletteWheel.png").getImage();
        spinSpeed = 5;
        speedDeduction = 0;

        add(startTimer);
        startTimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                time.start();
            }
        });

    }

    JButton startTimer = new JButton("Spin wheel");

    Timer time = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            speedDeduction += 0.0001;
            spinSpeed -= speedDeduction;
            rotationAngle += spinSpeed;
            if (spinSpeed <= 0) {
                time.stop();
                System.out.println(rotationAngle);
                System.out.println(rotationAngle/(365/38));
                System.out.println(Slices[Integer.valueOf(rotationAngle/(365/38))]);
                

            }
            repaint();
        }

    });

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        if (rotationAngle >= 365) {
            rotationAngle -= 365;
        }
        double rotationAngleRad = Math.toRadians(rotationAngle);
        g2d.rotate(rotationAngleRad, 600, 600);
        g2d.drawImage(image, 200, 200, null);

        int[] xPoints = {575, 600, 625};
        int[] yPoints = {200, 250, 200};
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: At 0 degree's you take the first element, which is a 1 - shouldn't 0 be the first element of the slice?

Comment: @Andrew Thx, I tried flipping the list of numbers but forgot that the 0 always had to be first.

Comment: is it correct that the rotation angle is being compared to 365 instead of 360? maybe I am missing something there. Could you provide more details about your issue? such as a log of messages of what the program is doing? the desired output and the one you are getting? Maybe adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: BTW despite of a full rotation being 360° (see previous comment), also be aware that `rotationAngle/(365/38)` is being evaluated as integer divisions, that is,  rounded down to the next integer (e.g.  `180 / (360/38)` will result in `20`)

Comment: BTW2 I would also declare `rotationAngle` as double; so `rotationAngle += spinSpeed;` works *smoother*; and write `Slices[(int)(0.5 + rotationAngle/(360.0/38.0))]` (actually I would rename `Slices` to `slices` according to Java Code Convention)

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm not a math major, so if anyone can clarify I've evaluated it correctly, feel free.  It appears to be correct, using double-zero for index 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to obtain the sector a specified angle will reside in.

Note, you'll have to use an array that begins with double-zero, working in the clockwise direction.

As others have mentioned, make sure to use *360*, and not *365*.

Double-zero lies within *355.26 and 4.73 °, approximately*.
For any other value, first subtract the *bound*, which is the *sector angle ÷ 2*, to negate the double-zero sector, then divide by the *sector angle*, finally adding *1* at the end to accommodate the initial double-zero negation.

```java
/** uses [a, b) */
int index(float angle) {
    float value = 360 / 38f;
    float bound = value / 2;
    if (angle >= 360 - bound || angle < bound) return 0;
    else return (int) ((angle - bound) / value) + 1;
}
```

To aid in defining whether it is a *Red* or *Black*, you can use an *enum*.
I am using *-1* to represent the double-zero.

```java
enum Sector {
    DOUBLE_ZERO, ZERO, RED, BLACK;

    static Sector number(int value) {
        return switch (value) {
            case -1 -> DOUBLE_ZERO;
            case 0 -> ZERO;
            case 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36 -> RED;
            case 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35 -> BLACK;
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(value));
        };
    }
}
```

Here is a basic implementation of these procedures.

```java
int[] sectors = {
    -1, 27, 10, 25, 29, 12, 8, 19, 31, 18,
    6, 21, 33, 16, 4, 23, 35, 14, 2, 0,
    28, 9, 26, 30, 11, 7, 20, 32, 17,
    5, 22, 34, 15, 3, 21, 36, 13, 1
};
Random random = new Random();
float angle = random.nextFloat() * 360f;
int index = index(angle);
int number = sectors[index];
Sector sector = Sector.number(number);

System.out.println("angle = " + angle);
System.out.println("index = " + index);
System.out.println("number = " + number);
System.out.println("sector = " + sector.name().toLowerCase());
```

Here are a few outputs.

```
angle = 198.36185
index = 21
number = 9
sector = red

angle = 18.213615
index = 2
number = 10
sector = black

angle = 3.0296087
index = 0
number = -1
sector = double_zero
```

Comment: Did you notice that the OP was using 365 as the number of degrees in a circle?

Comment: @JimGarrison, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: note that since `rotationAngle` is declared as an `int`, `rotationAngle / 360` results in zero, ergo `index` will also be zero

Comment: The OP's definition of a circle is incorrect. He's assuming there are 365 degrees in a circle, which would throw off all calculations.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I'm misunderstanding your inquiry.  It's written in my answer, how would I not be aware of it?

Comment: @user16320675, they're not evaluating `rotationAngle / 360`, though.

Comment: @Reilas but the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcfY3.png) in this answer was doing it before it was [edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4lkr.png) about 3 hours ago. The comment was on this answer, not on the question! Since the integer division was replaced, I assume you did understand my previous comment!

Comment: @user16320675, it was working in my code.  I must have forgot to mention to change it to a _double_.  I think I was presuming they would have read the other comments.  At any rate, this solution uses a _float_, so the values are valid.